# Powershell command to move forward and backward in array

Tags: powershell

I would like to be able to add functionality to a PowerShell script to move one spot forwards or one spot backwards when in a `foreach` loop. While looping through a `foreach` statement, is it possible to move forwards and backwards or to identify what point in the array the current item lies?

Edit - the items in the array are files, not numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Yes - it's called a `for` loop!

For data structures that we can *index* into (arrays, lists, etc.), the `foreach` loop statement can easily be translated to a `for` loop statement, like so:

```
# This foreach loop statement
foreach($item in $array){
  Do-Something $item
}

# ... is functionally identical to this for loop statement
for($i = 0; $i -gt $array.Length; $i++){
  $item = $array[$i]
  Do-Something $item
}
```

Since we have direct access to the current *index* (via `$i`) in the `for` loop, we can now use that as an offset to "look around" that position in the array:

```
$array = @(1,2,3,4)

for($i = 0; $i -lt $array.Length;$i++)
{
    $item = $array[$i]
    if($i -gt 0){
      # If our index position $i is greater than zero, 
      # then there must be _at least_ 1 item "behind" us
      $behind = $array[$i - 1]
    }

    if($i -lt ($array.Length - 1)){
      # Not at end of array, we can also "look ahead"
      $ahead = $array[$i + 1]
    }

}
```

Be careful about checking that you don't use an `$i` value greater than `$array.Length` (which would result in `$null`) or less than `0` (in which case PowerShell will start reading the array backwards!)

Comment: Is it possible to wrap this in a `foreach` statement or is that now unnecessary? I'd like to have a `foreach` to address each item in the `$array` but with a user prompt to move backwards or forwards through each item in the array.

Comment: Does `++` work for more than numbers? In this case the items in the array are files (images).

Comment: @Garrett Sorry, that was a lousy answer, updated it with a bit more context/explanation. FWIW, `++` only increment numbers, but `$i` is already a number - regardless of what's _inside_ the array! :)

Comment: Thanks for the follow up and the additional info, will work with this and see what I can get to work for my tool. Take care